# How to always go back to a certain activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I've seen the examples on this topic such as using `finish()` and `flags` (still unsure about flags). My problem is I have 3 activitys, Login, SignUp, and Home. The user can reach home by either logging in or signing up. Home contains a logout button. The desired action is when the user presses log out they are returned to the Login screen. However if the user signs up and then logs out they are returned to the sign up activity again. What is the best solution/strategy? Please provide an example or good explanation.[image]

Comment: Do you reach your `SignUpActivity` from `LoginActivity`?

Comment: @Apoorv yes apologies the original diagram was wrong, its been updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.if you dont want user to redirect to signup after logout if he came from signup screen then you can use finish() on your sign up screen intent. 
call finish() in signup before startActivity() for home.
and on home use

```
Intent i=new Intent(HomeActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(i);
HomeActivity.this.finish();
```

2.If you want user to back on signup actvity then dont call finish on your login and signup activity when u redirect user to home activity and call finish() on logout button. Here u will redirect to activity from where u have come

Answer (score 0):

When you want to reach `HomeActivity` from `SignUpActivity` do this

```
Intent intent=new Intent(SignUpActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
SignUpActivity.this.finish();
```

and when you are doing login do this

```
Intent intent=new Intent(LoginActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
LoginActivity.this.finish();
```

and when you want to logout

```
Intent intent=new Intent(HomeActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
HomeActivity.this.finish();
```

so you will have only one `Activity` in your stack when you logout and that's `LoginActivity`

Answer (score 0):

In Login activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Home.class);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

In Signup activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Home.class);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

In Home activity, run this when logout is clicked:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Login.class);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```